# How to do an In Statement with a sub query returning 2 columns and one of the columns is a Count

Tags: sql, db2

I have this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM GUITARS.FENDER
WHERE FENDER.GUITARTYPE IN (
SELECT GUITARTYPE,Count(*)
FROM GUITARS.GUITAR_TYPE
WHERE GuitarColor = 'RED'
Group By GUITARTYPE
Having Count(*) = 1)
```

Basically I want to make sure I am only checking the Guitartypes that don't have duplicates with a count. The issue is the IN is only checking for 1 column, but i need the count(*)in there for instances of more than one guitar type. Is there a way to make this query work, or possible another way around doing the count.

Comment: No need to have the count(*) in the subquery....you can limit it in the subquery using the having clause without it being in the select line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to have the count(*) returned in the select statement, having the group by and the count(*) is sufficient.

```
SELECT *
FROM GUITARS.FENDER
WHERE FENDER.GUITARTYPE IN (
    SELECT GUITARTYPE
    FROM GUITARS.GUITAR_TYPE
    WHERE GuitarColor = 'RED'
    Group By GUITARTYPE
    Having Count(*) = 1)
```

Adding the code so it looks right.